# Get DNS suffix with nodejs

Tags: node.js, dns, network-programming

With NodeJs, the "dns" library don't use dns suffix to resolve hostname.

```
await dns.promises.resolve('foo.ad.toto.fr')
>>> [ '10.1.40.205' ]
await dns.promises.resolve('foo')
>>> Error: queryA ENOTFOUND foo
```

```
ipconfig /all

Configuration IP de Windows

   Nom de l’hôte . . . . . . . . . . : arc-pc-y399539
   Suffixe DNS principal . . . . . . : ad.toto.fr
   Type de noeud. . . . . . . . . .  : Hybride
   Routage IP activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Proxy WINS activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Liste de recherche du suffixe DNS.: ad.toto.fr
```

So I need to get "DNS Suffixes list" but I don't know how...

And i can't parse return of command "ipconfig" since it must be compatible with windows and linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the package "systeminformation" to get primary dns suffix, but not the "DNS Suffixes list"